# Integral arising from QED vacuum polarization

Tags: integration

I would like to integrate

$$\int_0^1(1-x^2)e^{-a(1-x^2)^{-1/2}}dx$$

for $a>0$.

One obvious substitution, $y=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$, produces

$$\int_1^\infty y^{-4}(y^2-1)^{-1/2}e^{-a y}dy$$

but neither I nor Mathematica can do this integral either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Excluding numerical integration, I should do it using series expansion built at $x=0$. This would give
$$\left(1-x^2\right) e^{-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=e^{-a}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \, x^{2k}+O(x^{2k+2}) \right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & b_k \\
 1 & -\frac{a}{2}-1 \\
 2 & \frac{a^2}{8}+\frac{a}{8} \\
 3 & -\frac{a^3}{48}+\frac{a^2}{16}+\frac{a}{16} \\
 4 & \frac{a^4}{384}-\frac{5 a^3}{192}+\frac{5 a^2}{128}+\frac{5 a}{128} \\
 5 & -\frac{a^5}{3840}+\frac{a^4}{192}-\frac{7 a^3}{256}+\frac{7 a^2}{256}+\frac{7
   a}{256} \\
 6 & \frac{a^6}{46080}-\frac{11 a^5}{15360}+\frac{23 a^4}{3072}-\frac{7
   a^3}{256}+\frac{21 a^2}{1024}+\frac{21 a}{1024} \\
 7 & -\frac{a^7}{645120}+\frac{7 a^6}{92160}-\frac{a^5}{768}+\frac{29
   a^4}{3072}-\frac{55 a^3}{2048}+\frac{33 a^2}{2048}+\frac{33 a}{2048} \\
 8 & \frac{a^8}{10321920}-\frac{17 a^7}{2580480}+\frac{41 a^6}{245760}-\frac{97
   a^5}{49152}+\frac{1093 a^4}{98304}-\frac{429 a^3}{16384}+\frac{429
   a^2}{32768}+\frac{429 a}{32768} \\
 9 & -\frac{a^9}{185794560}+\frac{a^8}{2064384}-\frac{5 a^7}{294912}+\frac{29
   a^6}{98304}-\frac{177 a^5}{65536}+\frac{103 a^4}{8192}-\frac{5005
   a^3}{196608}+\frac{715 a^2}{65536}+\frac{715 a}{65536}
\end{array}
\right)$$ and integrate termwise to get
$$\int_0^1\left(1-x^2\right) e^{-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\,dx=e^{-a}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {b_k}{2k+1} \right)$$

Limited to $n=9$, this would give the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0 & 0.6666666667 & 0.6666666667 \\
 1 & 0.2123631665 & 0.2125607905 \\
 2 & 0.07059996854 & 0.07043172674 \\
 3 & 0.02383555255 & 0.02381813925 \\
 4 & 0.008134307224 & 0.008161937294 \\
 5 & 0.002812734609 & 0.002823407002 \\
 6 & 0.0009851151098 & 0.0009836552422 \\
 7 & 0.0003474991861 & 0.0003446169740 \\
 8 & 0.0001224830345 & 0.0001212798570 \\
 9 & 0.00004289847190 & 0.00004284093275 \\
 10 & 0.00001493941267 & 0.00001518064585
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

With a subsitution $x=\sin{t}$, $dx=\cos{t}\,dt$:
$$I(a)=\int_0^1(1-x^2)e^{-a(1-x^2)^{-1/2}}dx$$
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^3{t})e^{-a(\sec{t})}dt$$

With the Feyman trick:

$$I'(a)=-\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^2{t})e^{-a(\sec{t})}dt$$
$$I''(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos{t})e^{-a(\sec{t})}dt$$
$$I'''(a)=-\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-a(\sec{t})}dt$$
$$I^{(4)}(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sec{t}e^{-a(\sec{t})}dt$$
$$I^{(5)}(a)=-\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-a(\sec{t})}\sec^2{t}dt$$
$$I^{(6)}(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sec^3{t}e^{-a(\sec{t})}dt$$

Obvioulsy $I''(0)=1$ and $I'''(0)=-\pi/2$. Integrating by parts $I(a)$, with $u=\cos^2(t)e^{-a\sec(t)}\,dt$ and $dv=\cos(t)dt$, then $v=\sin(t)$ and $du=\Big[-2\sin(t)\cos(t)e^{-a\sec(t)} - a\sin(t)e^{-a\sec(t)} \Big] dt$ :

\begin{align}
I(a) &=  \lim_{ t\to \pi/2^{-} } \sin(t) \cos^2(t)e^{-a\sec(t)}  - \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(t) \Big[-2\sin(t)\cos(t)e^{-a\sec(t)} - a\sin(t)e^{-a\sec(t)} \Big] dt    \\
I(a) &=  2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2(t)\cos(t)  e^{-a\sec(t)} dt  + a\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \sin^2(t) e^{-a\sec(t)} dt  \\
\end{align}

Using the identity $\sin^2(t)= 1- \cos^2(t)$:

\begin{align}
I(a) &=  2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(t)  e^{-a\sec(t)} dt - 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^3(t)  e^{-a\sec(t)} dt   + a  \int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-a\sec(t)} dt  - a   \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^2(t)  e^{-a\sec(t)} dt     \\
I(a) &= 2 I''(a) - 2I(a) - aI''(a) + aI'(a) \\
0 &= aI'''(a) - 2I''(a) - aI'(a) + 3I(a) \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

Remember that $I''(0)=1$, then if we evaluate $a=0$ in \eqref{1}, we can demostrate that $I(0)=2/3$  . If you derivate \eqref{1} :
$$
0 = aI^{(4)}(a) - I'''(a) -aI''(a) + 2I'(a) \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

If $\lim_{a\to 0^{+}}$ in \eqref{2}, $I'(0)=-\pi/4$ . Derivating \eqref{2} :
$$
aI^{(5)}(a) - aI'''(a) + I''(a) = 0  \label{3}\tag{3}
$$
Derivating \eqref{3} :
$$
aI^{(6)} + I^{(5)}(a) - a I^{(4)} = 0
$$
If $y(a)=I^{(4)}(a)$:
$$ a^2y''(a) + ay'(a) - a^2 y(a) = 0 $$

This is a [modified Bessel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) and the solution is:

$$ y(a)= c_1 I_0(a) + c_2 K_0(a);\quad \text{with }c_1,c_2\in \Bbb{R} $$

The $I_0,K_0$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind with $\alpha=0$, respectively. Then:

$$ I^{(5)}(a)= c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2}\Big(\frac{a}{2}\Big)^{2m} + c_2 \int_0^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh{\theta}}d\theta $$

If I integrate this with $a_0>0$ :

\begin{align}
& I^{(4)}(a) -  I^{(4)}(a_0) = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+1}}{2m+1} -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1} + c_2 \int_{a_0}^{a}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t\cosh{\theta}}d\theta dt   \\
& I^{(4)}(a) = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+1}}{2m+1} + c_2 \int_0^{\infty}\int_{a_0}^{a} e^{-t\cosh{\theta}} dt d\theta   -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1} + I^{(4)}(a_0)    \\
& I^{(4)}(a) = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+1}}{2m+1} + c_2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{   e^{-a_0\cosh(\theta)}  - e^{-a\cosh(\theta)}   }{\cosh(\theta)} d\theta -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1}     + I^{(4)}(a_0)  \\
& I'''(a) - I'''(0)  = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)(2m+1)} + c_2 \int_0^a \int_0^{\infty} \frac{   e^{-a_0\cosh(\theta)}  - e^{-t\cosh(\theta)}   }{\cosh(\theta)} d\theta dt -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1}a     + I^{(4)}(a_0)a  \\
\end{align}

And $I'''(0)=-\pi/2$, then:

\begin{align}
& I'''(a) = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)(2m+1)} + c_2  \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^a \frac{   e^{-a_0\cosh(\theta)}  - e^{-t\cosh(\theta)}   }{\cosh(\theta)} dt d\theta  -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1}a     + I^{(4)}(a_0)a - \pi/2       \\
& I'''(a) = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)(2m+1)}
+ c_2  \int_0^{\infty}\Bigg( \frac{e^{-a_0\cosh(\theta)}a}{\cosh(\theta)}  + \frac{ e^{-a\cosh(\theta)} -1   }{\cosh^2(\theta)} \Bigg) d\theta
 -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1}a     
+ I^{(4)}(a_0)a - \pi/2       \\
\end{align}

Then $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh^2(\theta)}d\theta =\bigg[\tanh(\theta)\bigg]_0^{\infty}=1$ :

\begin{align}
& I'''(a) = c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)(2m+1)}
+ c_2  \int_0^{\infty}\Bigg( \frac{e^{-a_0\cosh(\theta)}a}{\cosh(\theta)}  + \frac{ e^{-a\cosh(\theta)}  }{\cosh^2(\theta)} \Bigg) d\theta - c_2
 -   c_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m!)^2 4^m }\frac{a_0^{2m+1}}{2m+1}a     
+ I^{(4)}(a_0)a - \pi/2       \\
\end{align}

---

**In construction**

Comment: Impressive, for sure ! For the summation, the result seems to be $$\frac{\left(a^4+7 a^2+24\right) I_1(a)-2 a \left(a^2+6\right) I_0(a)}{a^4}$$ For the remaining integral, I am more than stuck. Waiting for your update. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to update this in a day of these

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was derivating $I^{(4)}$, so the answer was very bad, I am sorry